# Adding executable sss to bin path

Tags: command-line, paths

I'm trying to follow this instruction but I'm not sure how. I have very little knowldge of Linux.

> Add the executable "sss" to search path. In most installations this 
>       can be accomplished by linking the file to the "bin" subdirectory 
>       at user home.

Could I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

PATH is an environment variable that will list the directories to search for a command (script or binary).

Running `echo $PATH` on a terminal will output your current PATH variable.

Usually, the terminal recognizes directories called "bin" in the user home and add it to the PATH (this is done automatically when the *~/.profile* script is called by the terminal on invocation).

So what this instruction is telling you to do, is to create a symlink to your program on the *~/bin* folder, if that exists (or creating it and including the symlink if it doesn't).

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
ln -s path/to/your/program programname
```

Then you can call your program by just typing its name in the terminal.